# Google Cloud Create Function failed with cache miss on docker_layer_cache

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create my first Cloud Function, pointing to a branch on my Github repo mirrored on a Google Cloud Repository. However, the function fails to deploy and yields the following error:

Deployment failure:

```
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "c6a7ea692f4ddc9f7088c33d4c6e337420dcdc1452daa09efb5054117e10be57", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "MISS", "hash": "c6a7ea692f4ddc9f7088c33d4c6e337420dcdc1452daa09efb5054117e10be57", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}
```

Here is more from the error log:

```
protoPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"    
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail:  "paul.devito@output.com"     
  }
  methodName:  "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"    
  resourceName:  "projects/second-casing-278016/locations/us-west2/functions/RetentionPredictionFunction-TESTBRANCH"    
  serviceName:  "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"    
  status: {
   code:  3     
   message:  "Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "c6a7ea692f4ddc9f7088c33d4c6e337420dcdc1452daa09efb5054117e10be57", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "MISS", "hash": "c6a7ea692f4ddc9f7088c33d4c6e337420dcdc1452daa09efb5054117e10be57", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}"     
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2020-07-28T20:37:01.643381187Z"
```

And from the create function request log:

```
{
 insertId:  "fjgtmse38h4w"   
 logName:     
 operation: {
  first:  true    
  id:  "operations/c2Vjb25kLWNhc2luZy0yNzgwMTYvdXMtd2VzdDIvUmV0ZW50aW9uUHJlZGljdGlvbkZ1bmN0aW9uLVRFU1RCUkFOQ0gvX3ZfNWZtU2RITHM"    
  producer:  "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"    
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"    
  authenticationInfo: {…}   
  authorizationInfo: [1]   
  methodName:  "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"    
  request: {
   @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest"     
   function: {
    availableMemoryMb:  1024      
    entryPoint:  "daily_retention_prediction_procedure"      
    eventTrigger: {…}     
    ingressSettings:  "ALLOW_ALL"      
    labels: {
     deployment-tool:  "console-cloud"       
    }
    maxInstances:  1      
    name:        
    runtime:  "python37"      
    serviceAccountEmail:     
    sourceRepository: {
     url: 
    timeout:  "540s"      
   }
   location:    
  }
  requestMetadata: {…}   
  resourceLocation: {…}   
  resourceName:  
  serviceName:  "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"    
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2020-07-28T20:34:08.301085522Z"   
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type:  "cloud_function"    
 }
 severity:  "NOTICE"   
 timestamp:  "2020-07-28T20:34:07.489Z"   
}
```

The only other instance of this error I can find online is a Google outage, but the website shows all systems are go. What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

After checking the python code example for the Pub/Sub trigger I realized I was missing default arguments to the entry function:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    ...
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/helloworld/main.py